# Разбор исходного кода проектов

Tags: .net, visual-studio, opensource

В свете того, что приходится часто заниматься разбором исходного кода различных проектов как на работе, так и дома и это стало занимать значительное время, посвященное программированию, хочется узнать, а как вы изучаете исходный код проектов (для изменения или же для фана :) )? В первую очередь интересует более-менее полное понимание проекта.

На данный момент я попытался формализовать свои действия:

1. Понимание общей сути проекта и его настройка, если требуется.
2. Беглая оценка состава сборок проекта (какие по смыслу классы в нем находятся, определение причин выделения кода в отдельную сборку).
3. Анализ зависимостей между сборками, между классами и между методами классов(с использованием Solution explorer и Architecture explorer).
4. Визуальное чтение кода и мысленная интерпретация.
5. Если шаг 3 не помог, и код слишком сложен, поиск .юнит-тестов и проход по проекту с использованием отладки по одному из тестов.
6. Если тестов нет/их лень писать включается метод храповика(одновременно также уменьшающего нагрузку на память) в виде brain-dumping.
   http://writing-cures.livejournal.com/16633.html . Хотя этот метод и для писателей в основном, для программистов тоже катит, ибо еще Макконелл в своей книге сравнивал эти 2 профессии.
7. Если и это не помогает, все-таки пишем тесты и все-равно используем brain-dumping (ведя мысленный разговор с листочком бумаги).

Список наверняка не полный, однако на данный момент это все, что у меня есть.

Comment: почитал, сделал вывод - страдаешь фигней. Совет по п.3 - удобно читать код, через дебагер.

Comment: видимо у Вас полно свободного времени. Если изучаете код который написали у Вас на работе - просто спросите архитектуру. Если вы читаете код чужих проектов (с git'a например), то до хорошего обычно это не доведет, ибо всегда нужно знать, почему именно так сделали а не иначе, а тут уже никто Вам не объяснит. Так что думайте сами, пишите сами.

Comment: Я придерживаюсь того мнения, что прежде чем лезть в дебаггер стоит хотя бы для начала мысленно понять что делает код. Если программист сразу лезет в дебаггер, возможно он не слишком хорошо знает язык на котором разрабатывает?

Comment: @Viacheslav, это Вы очень метко заметили. По большей части вопрос навеян изучением кода одного из проектов на гитхабе, который на данный момент разработчики забросили. Наверное, действительно стоит с ними связаться.

Comment: первое, что нужно сделать - это попытаться скомпилировать/запустить программу и убедиться, что оно хоть как то работает. Следующей задачей будет доведение до работающего состояния (кто то забывает, к примеру, что есть русские локали, кто то забывает, что не все работают под администратором)...
А пока это будет доведено, придет минимальное понимание кода и направления движения.

Comment: @deque По собственной практике, начинать с пункта 7 - самое полезное, что можно придумать. То есть, если с открытой документацией написать пачку хороших `learning` тестов, то это обычно очень сильно поднимает уровень понимания кода и его зависимостей.

Answer (score 2):

[@deque](/users/9008/deque), про brain-dumping в данном контексте откровенно не понял.

Я (для C/C++)

1. пытаюсь найти "человеческое" описание/комментарии;
2. читаю .h файлы и файлы с конфигурацией (если они есть);
3. разбираюсь с тем, как строятся и инициализируются основные структуры данных (обычно они выявляются на шаге (2));

По ходу пункта (3) обычно вдоволь начитаешься разных участков кода (в т.ч. через grep) и уже сносно представляешь что и где делается.

Конечно, если проект в принципе работает, то собираю его и запускаю какие-то тесты.